InputText : unable to implement CSS for InputText
There is an issue with the InputText which is that it is unable to implement CSS from the razor.css file. This works if implementing the styling directly, but if it is not working if I am placing it in the razor.css file.
If you are wondering if this is due to CSS not connected to the .razor file, the other styling still works.
This is CreateContent.razor file:
<EditForm Model="diaryContent" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit" FormName="createEditForm">
    <table>
        ...
        <tr>
            <td class="title">
                <label>Diary Content</label>
            </td>
            <td class="details">
                <InputText @bind-Value="diaryContent.Content"
                           class="large-input"
                           title="Enter your diary content here"
                           placeholder="Write your diary content here..." 
                           />
            </td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
    <br/>
</EditForm>

This is CreateContent.razor.css:
.large-input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}

I am trying to increase the width of InputText, but it seems will not work without manually adding style in the .razor file instead of CSS file

Let me ask you, how familiar are you with how percentage-widths on non-block-level elements in CSS work?

As InputText is another "Component" and you are using isolation you need to use the ::deep selector:
::deep .large-input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}


Thanks for the tips, this works. By the way, what do you mean by isolation?

@LimSoongXian When you place css in a .razor.css it is called css isolation. Blazor uses an attribute on the html elements so the css is only applied to the elements within that component. The ::deep selector bypasses that attribute selector.
